# Elements stays in HBox after clearing

Tags: java, javafx

In my Blackjack app, after you lose or win game, it should erase all data from previous game, like score and cards images in HBox. It seem to work fine, but sometimes player cards disapear, but croupier cards stays, and he's playing alone..
Here is part of code, in which I erase all unnecessary data form last play:

```
    @FXML
    private Label playerScore;
    @FXML
    private HBox showPlayerCards;
    @FXML
    private HBox showCroupierCards;


     //rest of the code

    //and method, where it's all cleared:

private void endGameAlert() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setHeaderText("Przegrałeś!");
        alert.setContentText("Co chcesz teraz zrobić?");

        ButtonType buttonNew = new ButtonType("Nowa Gra");
        ButtonType buttonEx = new ButtonType("Wyjdź");

        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonNew, buttonEx);

        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

        if (result.get() == buttonNew) {
            showPlayerCards.getChildren().clear();
            showCroupierCards.getChildren().clear();
            player.eraseScore();
            croupier.eraseScore();
            player.eraseCards();
            croupier.eraseCards();
            playerScore.setText(Integer.toString(player.getScore()));
            player.setStatus("w grze");
        } else if (result.get() == buttonEx) {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }
```

Where is mistake, that sometimes don't clear HBox?

Comment: Though there is nothing wrong in `getChildren().clear()` and it should work, why don't you reload the FXML?

Comment: I was reloading it several times, also it was modified for other things, but problem still exist. If it was always at the beggining of the game, or in some point, I think I could find bug, but this error is on random play...

Comment: The point that I am trying to make here is that rather than clearing all the data in the current FXML Controller, just reload it if the user clicks on `buttonNew`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you explain me a little, how can I do this? Should I use FXMLLoader again?

Comment: Yes, load the FMXL again using `FXMLLoader` and just replace the Root Layout. Since you are loading the FXML again, a new instance of the controller will be created and all your controls will be in their initial stage.

Comment: `getChildren().clear()` should work as long as it is called on the correct thread - double check you are with `Platform.isFXApplicationThread()`. If not then all guarantees of correct UI behaviour go out the window :-)

Comment: When I don't use threads manually, can it still be that problem?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. If the hboxes are not getting cleared you have errors elsewhere in your code.